# Question about indentation on categorized list

Tags: lists, checkboxes, text, categorization, collapsing

wondered if I could get some help with this decision.

I currently have a list that gets populated for the user automatically. Within the list, the items will be categorized two ways (again automatically). My thought was to add 'category rows' that display in the same list view, and that could be collapsed while also showing the amount of items categorized.

I think the mechanism works pretty well, but I'm having some difficulty deciding on layout. I can't decide if the categorized items should be indented slightly underneath their respective category or if they should stay aligned. I should also mention that the items being categorized can then be multi-selected, with selection being indicated by checkmarks. Here are the two screenshots:

[image: Indented List]

[image: Non-indented List]

Any suggestions on which reads better? My gut is that indentation is ultimately the more appropriate way to go.. But something about the non-indented list feels clearer

Thanks!

[EDIT] Ignore the colors for the items. They relate to "rarity" of the items listed and multiple rarities can be listed under either of the two categories

Comment: I like indent...

Comment: Some questions: **(a)** Is "Ungrouped Items" an example of a category, or the "catch all" category for items not in another category? **(b)** Do either of your screen shots show "real" groups? **(c)** Are the colours significant to your question?

Comment: Aren't the colors right now used for categorization also? Will all these elements that belong to the same category together (one over the other)?

Comment: @TripeHound Yes, "Ungrouped Items" would be an example of one of the two categories, the other being "Parent Items". Not sure what you mean by real groups.. and no the colors are not relevant.

Comment: I meant were any of the other items shown "a group"... in the light of your response, the only other group would be "Parent items" (but it's not shown). I'd tend to go with the items indented slightly as in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a tree view for which the convention is indentation.  For more details of the convention, see an image of the Windows filesystem display (Windows Explorer, I think it's called, as opposed to Internet Explorer, which is the browser)